# String Matching KMP Algorithm break the loop while true?

Tags: java, c, string, data-structures

I'm a Chinese and my english is poor, I'll try to make myself understand, Thanks!

what happened: I am learning kmp, I wrote a code, the `while (  i < strlen(S) && j < strlen(T) )` is true, but it didn't go in the loop, and go to the `if(T.length == j)`:

> thanks PaulMcKenzie point out the difference, is the  `int next[strlen(T)];` casue the problem?  I change it to `int next[80]`, it dosen't make any difference;

code here:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "string.h"
void getNext(char T[], int next[]){
    int i=0, j=-1;
    next[0] = -1;
    while ( i < strlen(T) -1 ){
        if( -1 == j || T[i] == T[j]){
            i++;
            j++;
            next[i] = j;
        }else{
            j = next[j];
        }
    }
}

int kmp(char S[], char T[]){
    int next[strlen(T)];
    getNext(T, next);
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (  i < strlen(S) && j < strlen(T) ){   //look here please
        if ( -1 == j || S[i] == T[j]){
            i++;
            j++;
        } else{
            j = next[j];
        }
    }

    if(strlen(T) == j)
        return i - j;
    else
        return -1;
}

int main()
{
    char S[80],T[80];
    gets(S);
    gets(T);
    printf("%d", kmp(S, T));
}
```

test data:   jfaweiof   of

the next[0] = -1, next[1] = 0

I tried:

1. using IDEA debug:

[idea debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gc9o.png)

2. I tried Java code, it can get correct result

```
package com.peterjxl.string;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class KMP {

    public static void getNext(char[] T, int[] next){
        int i = 0, j = -1;
        next[0] = -1;
        while ( T.length -1 > i){

            if( -1 == j || T[i] == T[j]){
                ++i;
                ++j;
                next[i] = j;
            }else {
                j = next[j];
            }
        }
    }

    public static int KMP(char[] S, char[] T){
        int[] next = new int[T.length];
        getNext(T, next);
        int i=0, j=0;
        while (S.length > i && T.length > j){
            if(-1 == j || S[i] == T[j]){
                i++;
                j++;
            }else {
                j = next[j];
            }
        }
        if(T.length == j)
            return i-j;
        else
            return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String S, T;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        S = input.nextLine();
        T = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(KMP(S.toCharArray(), T.toCharArray()));
    }
}
```

3. I search the stackoverflow, It look like nobody had same question...
4. asking friend, asking in China Forum, get no answer...: https://segmentfault.com/q/1010000041451224

local environment：
win10 x64，

Clion 2021.3.2   Built in mingw：w649.0

Java 1.8 + idea: 2021.2.3 (Ultimate Edition)

any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: The code you have is not C++.  It is `C` code.  Specifically, this: `int next[strlen(T)];` is not valid C++.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (  i < strlen(S) && j < strlen(T) )
```

`unsigned int` compare to `signed int`, so the result in `C++` is `0xFFFFFFFF`

I change it to:

```
while (  i < (int)strlen(S) && j < (int)strlen(T) )
```

Now, the program works!

Answerer by brokkr, on the forum [SegmentFault](https://segmentfault.com/q/1010000041451224)